# Refresh page if timer is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have the following script. This is showing a countdown in a DIV. This is all good. But, if the counter is 0 (means; no days/hours/minutes/seconds) the page must automatically refresh one time. I'm searching for a solution for days but can't find a solution. Who can help me with this?

```
    $(function(){

var note = $('#note'),
    ts = new Date(2010),
    newYear = false;

if((new Date()) > ts){
    // The new year is here! Count towards something else.
    // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
    ts = (new Date('<?php echo $newDateUserTimerDate; ?>')).getTime() + 1*1*1*<?php echo $minutes; ?>*1000;
    newYear = false;
    //$start_date = new DateTime('2017-04-21 04:10:58');
}

$('#countdown').countdown({
    timestamp   : ts,
    callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){

        var message = "";

        message += days + " day" + ( days==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
        message += hours + " hour" + ( hours==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
        message += minutes + " minute" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'s' ) + " and ";
        message += seconds + " second" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'s' ) + " <br />";

        if(newYear){
            //message += "left until the new year!";
        }
        else {
            //message += "left to 10 days from now!";
        }

        note.html(message);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: What is the problem? "can't find a solution" is not a question about a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
location.reload();
```

For example:

```
 $(function(){

var note = $('#note'),
    ts = new Date(2010),
    newYear = false;

if((new Date()) > ts){
    // The new year is here! Count towards something else.
    // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
    ts = (new Date('<?php echo $newDateUserTimerDate; ?>')).getTime() + 1*1*1*<?php echo $minutes; ?>*1000;
    newYear = false;
    //$start_date = new DateTime('2017-04-21 04:10:58');
}

$('#countdown').countdown({
    timestamp   : ts,
    callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){

        var message = "";
    message += days + " day" + ( days==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
    message += hours + " hour" + ( hours==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
    message += minutes + " minute" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'s' ) + " and ";
    message += seconds + " second" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'s' ) + " <br />";

    if(newYear){
        //message += "left until the new year!";
        location.reload();
    }
    else {
        //message += "left to 10 days from now!";
    }

    note.html(message);


 }
});
```

Source:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: Thank you, but where and how can I integrate this in the code?

Comment: if(newYear){ //message += "left until the new year!"; }

Comment: I have added this in the IF line you mention but when the timer is complete it still show; 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds. There is no refresh. BUT if i change FALSE to TRUE on New year it is refreshing. But now it is always refreshing the page. All the time...

Comment: @DevInvestor: Where did you set `newYear` to `true`? This is kind of basic stuff. How are you debugging your script at present? Trace its execution using a pencil and some paper until you understand what your code is doing.

Comment: I did this on line 10 (newYear = false;). Also tried to have a check to only refresh once with adding a hash but now the page don't refresh anymore when the timer is complete... Any ideas?

Comment: After one refresh you need to set another countdown date and set newYear to false

Comment: Uh this I dont get (sorry still learning) can you give me an example for this?

Comment: OR show something and set newYear to false, than if(newYear) statement will have no effect and will not do another refresh

Comment: MAYBE it is better to make actions with javascript instead of reloading the page

Comment: for example you can set DIV element innerHtml so something else instead of refresh

Comment: I think the idea to have Newyear = false and have a check when the timer is done. I have now added this part in the code:  if((new Date()) < ts){
  // The new year is here! Count towards something else.
  // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
  ts = (new Date('<?php echo $newDateUserTimerDate; ?>')).getTime() + 1*1*1*<?php echo $minutes; ?>*1000;
  newYear = true;
  //$start_date = new DateTime('2017-04-21 04:10:58');
 }

Comment: But now (if there is a timer active) the page keeps reloading till the timer is done.

Comment: add something like that "if(newYear){newYear=false;}" in the beginning of page to stop reloads.